# CoreGraphics draw intersection of ellipses

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am coding up a ViewController that will have a legend on the left (A vertical list of labels and colored boxes: Category1: yellow, Category2: gree, Category 3: blue, etc....)

A user can tap an item in the list and then draw an ellipse within a UIView. I am tracking the touch events and can draw the ellipses no problem using core graphics.

The next step is to draw the intersection of two sets. Suppose a user draws a green ellipse and a red ellipse which overlap somewhat. I'd like to color the intersection yellow (red + green = yellow), but don't have any ideas on how to do this.

I have been able to accomplish this using alpha channels of < 1.0 as in the following image:
[image]

And then additionally, I need a way to have the user tap a point in the UIImage and then retrieve the intersection of all sets that that pixel is in.

Comment: This can easily be done using rectangles instead of ellipses. What would you think on the user end? Would you rather see ellipses? Even if you go them, they wouldn't be as straight forward to use as rectangles would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Core Graphics to draw the ellipses, you can change the [blend mode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000950) to create different looks. The blend mode you want is addition, but it doesn't appear to be supported by Core Graphics (possibly due to the Quantel patent, though I thought that had expired). You can probably create a similar effect by using 50% alpha and using normal mode. Or maybe one of the other modes will provide something that looks better.

If that's not going to work, you could do it in OpenGL using [additive blending](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/347328-additive-blending-how-to-do-it/).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. I am using 50% alpha in the image above. It doesn't really look so good because of the choice of colors (they don't blend in an interesting manner). 

I know OpenGL can do the job, but I'd rather keep it to CG for simplicity sake. GLKit has made things somewhat simpler, but it's still no where near as simple as CG.

Comment: Well, try it with the colors you suggested (red and green should make yellow, for example). Did any of the other blend modes you can use with `CGContextSetBlendMode()` look decent? `kCGBlendModeScreen` is a really good choice for something like this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer came from user1118321, but I'm posting this answer to have inline pictures rather than reply inline. First I selected a better set of colors for the venn diagram:

[image]

These colors overlap and hide each other. The solution was to use kCGBlendModeScreen:

[image]

However this augmented the original colors. The solution to this was to set the background to black:

[image]

For those code curious or lazy, here is some of the code. On the touchesBegan/Ended/Moved events I'm creating SMVennObjects, then drawing them in drawRect. SMVennObject merely contains two CGPoints and a UIColor (assigned in sequence using a static int).

```
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{        
    for(NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.vennObjects.count; index++){
        NSLog(@"drawing index %d", index);
        SMVennObject* vo = [self.vennObjects objectAtIndex:index];
        [self drawVennObject:vo context:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    }
}

-(void)drawVennObject:(SMVennObject*)vo context:(CGContextRef)cgContext{
    if((vo.pointBegin.x == 0 && vo.pointBegin.y == 0) ||
       (vo.pointEnd.x == 0 && vo.pointEnd.y == 0)){
        return;
    }

    CGContextBeginPath(cgContext);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cgContext, 2.0f);

    // Convert UIColor to raw values
    CGFloat red = 0.0;
    CGFloat green = 0.0;
    CGFloat blue = 0.0;
    CGFloat alpha = 0.0;
    [vo.color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha];
    alpha = 1.0;
    CGFloat color[4] = {red, green, blue, alpha};


    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgContext, kCGBlendModeScreen);

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(MIN(vo.pointBegin.x, vo.pointEnd.x),
                          MIN(vo.pointBegin.y, vo.pointEnd.y),
                          fabs(vo.pointBegin.x - vo.pointEnd.x),
                          fabs(vo.pointBegin.y - vo.pointEnd.y));

    // Draw ellipse
    CGContextSetFillColor(cgContext, color);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(cgContext, r);

    // Draw outline of ellipse
    CGContextSetStrokeColor(cgContext, color);
    CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(cgContext, r);

}
```